# Reading a crash report first time

Tags: c++, crash, crash-reports

Using Steam Crash reporting service and we have an error that is

> Win32 StructuredException at 00C6A290 : Attempt to read from virtual
>   address 5467 without appropriate access rights.

I think I understand the second part (the program read memory from an area that it should not have). But the first part I don't understand. Is 00C6A290 the same each time the program is executed (and does I can backtrace it somehow) or is it assigned by the program at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `00C6A290` is an address in memory (within the executable of your program or some code called from it). To my understanding this address is the address of the instruction which caused the exception. In general it may be different each time you run your program since it can be loaded to different memory regions by the OS.

Run your program in a debugger to see backtrace. Do you have the source code?

Comment: I have all the source code and the PC version was render in Visual Studio's 2013. This issue it's not being run in Visual Studio this is the a crash handler in the program that Valve provides.